# Count the frequency of functions written in my R script files?

Tags: r

I would like to tabulate how often a function is used in one or more R script files. I have found the function `NCmisc::list.functions.in.file`, and it is very close to what I want:

```
library(stringr)
cat("median(iris$Sepal.Length)\n  median(iris$Sepal.Width)\n library(stringr); str_length(iris$Species) \n", file = "script.R")
list.functions.in.file("script.R")

   package:base   package:stats package:stringr 
      "library"        "median"    "str_length"
```

Note that `median` is used twice in the script, but `list.functions.in.file` does not use this information, and only lists each unique function. Are there any packages out there that can produce such frequencies? And bonus for the ability to analyze a corpus of multiple R scripts, not just a single file.

(note this is NOT about counting function calls, e.g. in recursion, and I want to avoid executing the scripts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That [`NCmisc` function](https://github.com/nicholasjcooper/NCmisc/blob/master/NCmisc.R#L1756) is just a wrapper round `utils::parse` and `utils::getParseData`, so you can just make your own function (and then you don't need the dependency on `NCmisc`:

```
count.function.names <- function(file) {
  data <- getParseData(parse(file=file))
  function_names <- data$text[which(data$token=="SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL")]
  occurrences <- data.frame(table(function_names))
  result <- occurrences$Freq
  names(result) <- occurrences$function_names
  result
}
```

Should do what you want...

Comment: In order to count the functions explicitly defined in an R script file, which is why I came here, just change the 3rd line in the function written by @tim_yates: `function_names <- data$text[which(data$token=="FUNCTION")]`